# TM4C123G6PMI USB Device Communication

Tags: arm, embedded, texas-instruments

I have recently got my hands on a Tiva C series MCU and I would like to use it's USB capabilities.

My goal is to send commadns to the boards via USB and get a message back (acknowledge or error reporting)

Commands start with a capital letter followed by 3 digits like X123.

There is a sample code which I have modified to a bit, to get certain responses if the RxBuffer has the letter in it.

```
static uint32_t
EchoNewDataToHost(tUSBDBulkDevice *psDevice, uint8_t *pui8Data,
                  uint32_t ui32NumBytes)
{
    uint32_t ui32Loop, ui32Space, ui32Count;
    uint32_t ui32ReadIndex;
    uint32_t ui32WriteIndex;
    tUSBRingBufObject sTxRing;

    //
    // Get the current buffer information to allow us to write directly to
    // the transmit buffer (we already have enough information from the
    // parameters to access the receive buffer directly).
    //
    USBBufferInfoGet(&g_sTxBuffer, &sTxRing);

    //
    // How much space is there in the transmit buffer?
    //
    ui32Space = USBBufferSpaceAvailable(&g_sTxBuffer);

    //
    // How many characters can we process this time round?
    //
    ui32Loop = (ui32Space < ui32NumBytes) ? ui32Space : ui32NumBytes;
    ui32Count = ui32Loop;

    //
    // Update our receive counter.
    //
    g_ui32RxCount += ui32NumBytes;

    //
    // Dump a debug message.
    //
    DEBUG_PRINT("Received %d bytes\n", ui32NumBytes);

    //
    // Set up to process the characters by directly accessing the USB buffers.
    //
    ui32ReadIndex = (uint32_t)(pui8Data - g_pui8USBRxBuffer);
    ui32WriteIndex = sTxRing.ui32WriteIndex;

    while(ui32Loop)
    {
        UARTprintf("\n" );
        //
        // Copy from the receive buffer to the transmit buffer converting
        // character case on the way.
        //

        //
        // Is this a lower case character?
        //
        if((g_pui8USBRxBuffer[ui32ReadIndex] == 'L'))
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);
            UARTprintf("LEFT" );

        }
        else if((g_pui8USBRxBuffer[ui32ReadIndex] == 'R'))
        {
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_2);
            UARTprintf(" RIGHT " );

        }
        else
        {

            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, 0);
            GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, 0);
            //
            // Is this an upper case character?
            //
            if((g_pui8USBRxBuffer[ui32ReadIndex] >= 'A') &&
               (g_pui8USBRxBuffer[ui32ReadIndex] <= 'Z'))
            {
                //
                // Convert to lower case and write to the transmit buffer.
                //
                g_pui8USBTxBuffer[ui32WriteIndex] =
                    (g_pui8USBRxBuffer[ui32ReadIndex] - 'Z') + 'z';
            }
            else
            {
                //
                // Copy the received character to the transmit buffer.
                //
                g_pui8USBTxBuffer[ui32WriteIndex] =
                    g_pui8USBRxBuffer[ui32ReadIndex];
            }
        }

        //
        // Move to the next character taking care to adjust the pointer for
        // the buffer wrap if necessary.
        //
        ui32WriteIndex++;
        ui32WriteIndex = (ui32WriteIndex == BULK_BUFFER_SIZE) ?
                         0 : ui32WriteIndex;

        ui32ReadIndex++;
        ui32ReadIndex = (ui32ReadIndex == BULK_BUFFER_SIZE) ?
                        0 : ui32ReadIndex;

        ui32Loop--;
    }

    //
    // We've processed the data in place so now send the processed data
    // back to the host.
    //
    USBBufferDataWritten(&g_sTxBuffer, ui32Count);

    DEBUG_PRINT("Wrote %d bytes\n", ui32Count);

    //
    // We processed as much data as we can directly from the receive buffer so
    // we need to return the number of bytes to allow the lower layer to
    // update its read pointer appropriately.
    //
    return(ui32Count);
}
```

But I have no idea how to get the next 3 digits out of the buffer as numbers and simply write back messages to the host with a single command like UARTprintf for example.

Could you please get me on track with this?

Thanks guys,
Zoszko

Comment: You have a big decision to make: packets or streaming?  If you implement a virtual serial port type of *streaming* paradigm, then formally you should ignore packets and move data to buffers where you can look for units of meaning potentially *crossing packet boundaries*.  But if you build something around USB packets, then the simple solution is to have only have one piece of information per transfer, starting aligned at the beginning of the transfer's packet buffer. It might help to find and study the protocol of an existing peripheral that does something similar to what you are trying to do.